# vs 2012 ordered test - customize path to tests dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mstest, ordered-test

When I create ordered test, add some tests to it and open the *.orderedtest file with some text editor I have hardcoded path to test dll, for example:

```
storage="bin\Debug\sometest.dll"
```

I would like to have this path set based on visual studio configuration like this below which unfortunetally does not work:

```
storage="bin\$(Configuration)\sometest.dll"
```

Any idea how to do this?